# I am not able to find the error in this code . Problem is to cylindrically rotate an array by one

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
t= int(input())
while t>0:
    
    n =int(input())
    a =list(map(int,input().strip().split()))
    if n==1:
        print(a[0])
        
    else:
        c= []
        c.append(a[n-1])
        for i in range(n-1):
            c.append(a[i])
        for x in c:
            print(x,end =" ")
    t= t-1
# ERROR is :    !!!Wrong Answer
```

Possibly your code doesn't work correctly for multiple test-cases (TCs).

The first test case where your code failed:

Input:

```
2
1 2
```

Its Correct output is:

```
2 1
```

And Your Code's output is:

```
2 1 3 1 2 4 1 2 3 7 1 8 7 5 6 7 8 3 9 8 7 6 4 2 1 17 ...
```

---

But this is not the output with this input . On compile and run the output is same as expected but now it is changing my output.

Comment: It works for me tho...

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this question if the input handling was separated from the logic in question. Please re-write your code so that the input is a list. Your question isn't about the input handling.